# Help me making my next training plan

Tags: exercise, muscle, training, core

I finding good training for my own.

**STATE:**
Started home traning a week ago. (daily 90 min of traning)
I have not fixed training set for me yet. This period, only just doing as I can do. The first reason is I have no knowledge about how to make it. And second reason is to keep my interesting and sustainable.
ordinary my training set is almost going like next.

1. 3 set of Push-ups (1~3 normal, 3~5 kneeling, 10 on the wall is 1 set that is my limit)
2. Trying Leg Split Stretch. (from youtube teaching)
3. 50~100 squats.
4. And others (sit-up or plank, etc)

State is Age 33, Male, 1.85m height, 90kg weight, 26% fat, 64% muscles.
And I haven't muscle training experience.
My home training's target is to gain basic physical strength for 1 ~ 2 months.
(I heard a saying, "If you can't just a set of Push-ups or squat or other basics exercise with perfect position, don't do any other training except by that until you can do them 1 or more sets.")
When I reach goal, I will going to health gym, or other training centers.
So this question is about my future.

**My Final Targets:**
The lowest number is most I want. If mutually exclusive two or more items, I can ignore highest number.
1) I want good body control. (I'm sorry for I don't define it precisionly. my knowledge is so low. Not tired of long time walking or stand-up, and durability for my work(sitting down always))
2) I want good balance on my body. (I want feeling same power filled from my finger to my toe.)
3) I want agility and quickness. (I think my body is too heavy so I'm not good at outdoor activities with my friends)
4) I want cut my fat rate. (under 20%, up to 15%)
5) I want good shape (ex I want large chest and shoulder)
6) I want my weight to 80kg
*I'm sorry for my wording is not great... But next question or writing will be better because I will have more knowledge ...

**The Question.**
What is the best choose my after getting basic physical strength?
1) You are good now, progress home training that way. (In this case, recommending a lecture or youtube guide also helpful)
2) Going to health gym and telling your think to Personal Trainer.
3) Martial Arts is good for you (like jukido, Jiu-Jitsu)
4) Boxing
5) Swim
6) Pilates
7) Yoga
8) etc
Actually the case is just exmaple, You can explain your way.

**more thing**
My friends and online blogs said to me core muscle training (especially, inner-core) is good for you. but every saying of them has difference. So I very confused. for example, someone says plank is better than sit-up. But other one says just endure is not enough muscle stimulation for reinforce inner-core muscle. other example And someone says stomach vacuum is very good for directly train your transversus. But other one says more interest thing is balance between transversus and multifidus because your body can be twisted.
For my short knowledge, I don't know who's say is more important. Is core muscle(inner core?) is really most import for that i want? Than who knows the professional knowledge and how to train it?
All that thing is the things makes me confused so it makes me can't plan for next.
So finally i write a question to this page.

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you are trying to achieve its important you sort out a gym split. Doing squats, pushups and situps alone will do MINIMAL for your body. Infact doing these you will not see much of a change in your appearance at all. You want to join a gym and be doing the core compound exercises, bench press, barbell squats, deadlifts and shoulder press to begin with.

Training 90 mins a day is too long as well, keep it between 45-60 mins with higher intensity less rest. Buying a personal trainer is a waste of money in my eyes unless you are lazy as you can find everything you need on the internet, the only benefit is the added motivation and push to make sure you're doing everything right.

You could get a personal trainer for a month or so then mimic what he taught you mixing it with online routines. If you simply type muscle building gym split you will find thousands of plans to follow at the gym.

Diet is something that is very important especially when you're trying to lose weight as well, maybe something you should look in to especially if you want abs as well. As for training your core, situps are good... planks are good... you can't just do one or the other.